# Untyped module for function top-level export with properties

Tags: typescript, declaration

I'm trying to write a typings file for [changeset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/changeset).  I'm keeping it internal to my own project (this may be relevant later).  Changeset has two use cases:

```
import * as changeset from "changeset";

changeset({}, {}); // call as function
changeset.applyChanges({}, {}); // call a property on changeset
```

> the actual function in `changeset` is called `apply`, not `applyChanges`.  I've changed it here to avoid confusion with Javascript's built in `apply` method.

To accomplish this I've set up the above file (`index.ts`), and `changeset.d.ts`

```
declare function changeset(objA: any, objB: any): any;
declare module "changeset" {
    export function applyChanges(changes: any, obj: any): any;
}
```

---

`changeset.applyChanges(...)` works correctly, `changeset(...)` does not:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'typeof import("changeset")' has no call signatures.
```

My `.d.ts` is very similar to TypeScript's [suggestion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-function-d-ts.html), only missing `export = changeset;` at the bottom.  I don't fully understand why, but adding the export causes the import in `index.ts` to error out:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'changeset'.
```

As far as I can guess, the difference is that other `.d.ts` files are imported from `node_modules` whereas this one is implicately part of my project.

**Is there any way to include complex module declarations like this in a single project?**

---

**EDIT**

Tried a different way:

```
declare module "changeset" {
    const changeset: {
        (objA: any, objB: any): any;
        applyChanges: (changes: any, obj: any) => any;
    };
    export = changeset;
}
```

Same error as before: `changeset.applyChanges(...)` works correctly, `changeset(...)` does not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your type is fine, but if the `changeset` module has a default export (the main function, with properties on it that are also functions), you probably want to import it like so:

```
import changeset from "changeset";
```

Comment: AHHHHHH I had `esModuleInterop` on.  You nailed it - thanks!